# Do functions auto different time PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to do a auto cleanup function and somehow my code dosent work the way i want it to do.

```
function autoclean() {
    $todo = array('fetchnews|15', 'sayhello|20');

    foreach ($todo as $do) {
        $do = explode('|', $do);
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT txt FROM x_other WHERE title='".$do[0]."'") or sqlalert(__FILE__, __LINE__);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);

        if ($row[0] + $do[1] > time())
            return;
        mysql_query("UPDATE x_other SET txt=".time()." WHERE title='".$do[0]."'") or sqlalert(__FILE__, __LINE__);
        if (!mysql_affected_rows())
            return;
        $do[0]();
    }
}
```

This is supposed to do fetxhnews() every 15 second and sayhello() every 20 second.
The first one works perfectly but sayhello() runns when fetchnews() runs for the second time (30 sec).

EDIT: I found why it didnt work.

```
function autoclean() {
    $todo = array('fetchnews|15', 'sayhello|20');

    foreach ($todo as $do) {
        $do = explode('|', $do);
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT txt FROM x_other WHERE title='".$do[0]."'") or sqlalert(__FILE__, __LINE__);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);


        if ($row[0] + $do[1] < time()) {
            mysql_query("UPDATE x_other SET txt=".time()." WHERE title='".$do[0]."'") or sqlalert(__FILE__, __LINE__);
            $do[0]();
        }
    }
}
```

The return; killed it. That code above now works.
Or is it still a better solution to this? want it to be as fast as possible

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: Yes it would be if $do[0] was a post or get, i felt that mysql_real_escape_string was unnecessary to this code. or am i wrong?

Comment: it would, but i like  to post my warning whenever i see something like this

Comment: Are you trying to execute fetchnews every 15 and sayhello every 20 seconds?

Comment: Then this is not the way to do it. You need some kind of endless loop or even better a [Cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) or something that is designed to do this

Comment: Any reason to not use ajax with setInterval?